# Python Counter with a certain count

Tags: python, python-3.x, collections, counter

I know that you can use `counterObjectName.most_common(n)` to get the `n` most common Counter elements. However, is there a built-in function that would allow me to get the Counter elements with a count of a certain value or greater than/less than a certain value?

I know that this can be accomplished with a loop but I just wanted to see if there was a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: No there isn't a built-in method for this.

Comment: The only way I can think of is to use a filter/loop. If you're worried about runtime efficiency, I'd loop over `most_frequent` and `break` when you breach the threshold